# Pepper and tracking Kids

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I have a case where I am trying to create some experiences with Pepper and with kids. Although Pepper is able to detect Adults using the face tracking, it is having a difficult time tracking kids ( of age 5-10 years, for example ). Is there anything I can do to make Pepper track faces based on certain demographics criteria ( Like, try to track kids who are less than age of 10 to build certain experiences ). I have gone through the documentation here ( http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/peopleperception/alfacedetection.html#alfacedetection ) but have not found any information for my specific use case. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try https://ai.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: On the current released version, Pepper cannot find people less than say 1m20. So a small kids or a sitted adult won't be detected correctly thus tracked.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway tracking specifically kids instead of adults would require specific code you'll have to program, not too hard, but will require some days or coding&testing.
If I were you, I'll proceed like that, humbly:

- deactivate autonomous life
- move the head randomly around lower position
- when found a face, look at the age estimation (see ALFaceCharacteristics in documentation)

  - if it's the good range, lock it and track it (with your own tracker OR dig into the ALTracker documentation to find if you can specify the user to track).
  - If not, search again...

Comment: hey, Thanks. That's a great approach. I'll look into it.